# deep copy using reflection java

Tags: java, reflection, deep-copy

I can't get a container from the class field using reflection. I tried the method below, but got an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at java.util.Collections.addAll(Collections.java:5455)
```

```
public static void copy(Object from, Object to) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<?> fromClass = from.getClass();
        Class<?> toClass = to.getClass();
        Field[] sourceFields = fromClass.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field fromField : sourceFields) {
            Field toField = toClass.getDeclaredField(fromField.getName());
            toField.setAccessible(true);
            fromField.setAccessible(true);
            if (fromField.getType().equals(toField.getType())) {
                if (!(fromField.getType() == String.class || fromField.getType().isPrimitive())) {
                        if (fromField.getType().isAssignableFrom(List.class)) {
                            List list = (List) fromField.get(from);
                            List list1 = (List) toField.get(to);
                            Collections.addAll(list1,list);
                            toField.set(to, fromField.get(from));
                        } else if (fromField.getType().isAssignableFrom(Set.class)) {
                            Set set = (Set) fromField.get(from);
                            Set set1 = (Set) toField.get(to);
                            set1.clear();
                            set.addAll(set1);
                            toField.set(to, fromField.get(from));
                        }
                } else {
                    toField.set(to, fromField.get(from));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't want to use methods of copying via serialization, I'm interested in reflection.

Comment: It appears that the list you're trying to add to doesn't support the `add` operation. You might want to debug this and see what implementation of `List` you're dealing with.

Comment: Take the getClass of the toField to see what List implementation it is. Some implementation do not support `add` (like `Arrays.asList`). The implementation class is a child of AbstractListClass without own add, You can check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this for training I hope? If not then use some opensource library, it's a lot harder than you think - [check this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-deep-copy).

Your problem is that you are adding to the `to` list, and the `to` list is an implementation that does not support adding (btw then you are ignoring the result). I suggest creating a new list and reassiging it, instead of adding to the existing one.

```java
List list = (List) fromField.get(from);
List list1 = (List) toField.get(to);
List newList = new ArrayList();
if(list != null)
  Collections.addAll(newList,list);
if(list1 != null)
  Collections.addAll(newList,list1);
toField.set(to, newList);
```

Similar thing with `Set` - your current code for `Set` doesn't make any sense, it operates on `Class` objects.